# What is carried interest, and its associated loophole?

Tags: taxes, tax-exemption

My motivation is to understand the carried interest loophole. A far as I understand, it is a method of tax avoidance.

Ideally, I like to understand that tax evasion loophole, but I think the main part I need to understand is carried interest.

First, I try to understand concept of carried interest, at least on a high level. I consulted the [Wikipedia page for carried interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carried_interest) article. As a layman in this area, I found that I miss various terms and underlying concepts to understand that explanation. To many to get the big picture.

Can you explain carried interest, and ideally the associated tax evasion scheme too, at a high level?

Answer (score 4):

Say there are 4 investor, contribute 25 ea and total fund of 100. They appoint a Fund Manager and he is paid 25 as management fee and it is expected that the fund will reach 150 in say 2 years time.

The 25 paid to Fund Manager is charged as salary and taxed at per tax brackets. The other share holders get back 125 divided as per their contribution [equally in this example]

The other option is; these 4 investors will contribute 24 ea; total of 96. Appoint a fund manager who will contribute 4 for a total fund of 100. The agreement is Fund Manager will give a return of say 10%. Post this his share of profit is 50%. He is given a fund management fee of 5. The agreement also specifies he must return all the capital 100 as well as guaranteed return of 10% before he takes his share.

The fund manager achieves 150 same as previous example.

A 10% guaranteed return, means 110 less of 5 paid to fund manager as fees. So 105. Of the remaining 40 [150-110]; the fund Manager gets 50%, i.e. 20 and remaining 20 goes to the investors.

So the investors got 105+20 same as previous example. Divided as per contributions.
The fund manager got 5 as fees; taxed as per tax brackets.
The 20 he made is treated as capital gains / carried interest on the 4 that he invested. This is now taxed as per the capital gains tax bracket.

This can't be taxed as salary/fee income as it involves contributing to capital as well as guaranteeing returns. This is treated as capital gains from taxation point of view.

Arguably one can have different distributions of capital gains; it goes back to the question of who is taking the risk.

Some of the reasons it is structured this way is to incentive the fund manager to generate maximum possible returns. Some is to gain tax advantage.